# How do I use Cisco WebEx Connect IM on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, webex, cisco-jabber

How do I use Cisco WebEx Connect IM on Mac OS X, it seems to be using Jabber protocol.

Answer (score 1):

It's not officially supported yet, they have been talking about "coming soon" for quite a while - from the support thread "he Mac client has been pushed back a little and is tracking to end of the first quarter of the 2011 calendar year" https://www.myciscocommunity.com/thread/1847

there are some configs that you could possibly use a jabber gateway to access webex connect, so in theory Adium or iChat would work. I have not been able to verify this due to my employer using an SSO gateway between the client and the server.

Cisco now has web chat for webex connect - im.ciscowebex.com and is usable in most browsers including Safari.

If your employer uses SSO (single sign on) then you may have to go through their web gateway and authentication process.